# UMA detection, available UMBs

Tags: x86, osdev, x86-16

The Upper Memory Area of a PC (the area between 640 KB and 1024 KB) is reserved for video memory and ROM bios.

According to [OSDev's Wiki](http://wiki.osdev.org/Memory_Map_%28x86%29#.22Low.22_memory_.28.3C_1_MiB.29"), [memory detection](http://wiki.osdev.org/Detecting_Memory_%28x86%29#Detecting_Low_Memory) regarding legacy PCs (PC/XT/AT compatibles) is restricted to int 0x12, since the int 0x15 related interrupts were not available at the time.

Suppose we have a 8086 or 80286 with 1 Mb of RAM. What would be the best way to detect which parts of the UMA are available (UMB blocks), and thus usable by programs?

Is there any way to utilize the complete range of the 1 Mb (real) RAM? Since the 16-bit addressing allows only for 1 Mb, and some of it is always going to be mapped to video memory and various ROMs? I am referring to real mode, not 80286 protected mode.